# Сохранение фото из моб. приложения на cordova --> node.js

Tags: node.js, cordova

Всем привет. Не получается сохранить фото на сервере (node.js), отправленное с мобильного приложения (cordova).
Код на клиенте:

```js
function get_picture() {
  //myApp.alert('функция get_picture 1');
  navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) {
        myApp.alert('Ошибка загрузки, вы не выбрали фото.');
      },{
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
      }
  );
}

function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
  var options = new FileUploadOptions();
  options.fileKey="my_avatar";
  options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
  options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

  var params = new Object();
  params.value1 = "test";
  params.value2 = "param";

  options.params = params;
  options.chunkedMode = false;

  var ft = new FileTransfer();

  var query = query11+'avatar';
  var headers = {'headerParam':'ddd_p'};

  options.headers = headers;

  ft.upload(imageURI, query, win, fail, options);
}

function win() {
  console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
  console.log("Response = " + r.response);
  myApp.alert("Успешно, отправлено байт = " + r.bytesSent);
  alert(r.response);
}
//если ошибка
function fail(error) {
  myApp.alert("Ошибка загрузки: Code = " + error.code);
}
```

Код на сервере:

```js
app.post('/avatar', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.method);
    console.log(req.headers);
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.url);
    console.log('req.body'+ req.body);
    console.log('ответ'+ res.file);

    var user_header = req.headers.headerparam;
    console.log('user_header = ' + user_header);

    var storage = multer.diskStorage({ //multers disk storage settings
      destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './app/files/')
      },
      filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-avatar-'+user_header+'.' + file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length -1])
      }
    });
    var upload = multer({ //multer settings
      storage: storage,
      fileFilter : function(req, file, callback) { //file filter
        if (['txt'].indexOf(file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length-1]) === -1) {
          return callback(new Error('Wrong extension type'));
        }
        callback(null, true);
      }
    }).single('my_avatar');
    upload(req,res,function(err) {
      if (err) {
        res.json({error_code: 1, err_desc: err});
        return;
      }
      if (!req.file) {
        res.json({error_code: 1, err_desc: "No file passed"});
        return;
      }
    })

  });
```

Вот, что выдает в консоль:

```js
POST
{ 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=+++++',
  cookie:
   'connect.sid=s%3AlKA2e6TZRAeIRRrDjZL8qv_lsE-Ya-e-.t2Na3QxvmhOMJfoOuUhPsweQo6eD0sdbJF%2FeoWbZSNA',
  headerparam: 'ddd_p',
  'content-length': '6670',
  'user-agent':
   'Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 6.0; Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280 Build/MRA58K)',
  host: '..........',
  connection: 'Keep-Alive',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip' }
{}
/avatar
req.body[object Object]
ответundefined
user_header = ddd_p
POST /avatar 200 72.879 ms - 48
```

На стороне сервера даже не проверяет на расширение файла (должен выдавать ошибку, т.к "txt". Хотя размер совпадает.
Что не так? Где ошибка? На стороне клиента или сервера?

Comment: А Вы не пробовали использовать `multer` так, как это задумано? То есть, вызывать функцию-переменную `upload()` в качестве middleware: `app.post('/avatar', upload, function (req, res) {...`. Для этого, она, конечно, должна быть определена снаружи этого обработчика.

Comment: судя по выводу в консоле - никакой файл на сервер отправлен не был. У Вас там пустой объект

Answer (score 0):

Сам разобрался. На стороне клиента - все в порядке.
На сервере код чуть по другому:

```js
app.post('/avatar',  function (req, res) {

    var user_header = req.headers.headerparam;
    console.log('user_header = ' + user_header);

    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'c:/........')
      },
      filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + 'avatarka' + Date.now()+'.jpeg')
      }
    });

    var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('my_avatar');

    upload(req,res,function(err){
      if(err){
        res.json({error_code:1,err_desc:err});
        return;
      }
      if(!req.file){
        res.json({error_code:1,err_desc:"No file passed"});
        return;
      }

    });

    res.sendStatus(200);

  });
```

Comment: а проблема-то, в чем была?

Comment: Я по другому путь сохранения сделал. (прописал полный с:\\...) и убрал проверку на расширение.